# Distributing a loop to different machines of a cluster in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, distributed-computing

Here is a for loop that I'm running in my code:

```
 for(x<-0 to vertexArray.length-1)
  {
    for(y<-0 to vertexArray.length-1)
      {
        breakable {

          if (x.equals(y)) {
            break
          }
          else {
            var d1 = vertexArray(x)._2._2
            var d2 = vertexArray(y)._2._2
            val ps = new Period(d1, d2)

            if (ps.getMonths() == 0 && ps.getYears() == 0 && Math.abs(ps.toStandardHours().getHours()) <= 5) {
              edgeArray += Edge(vertexArray(x)._1, vertexArray(y)._1, Math.abs(ps.toStandardHours().getHours()))
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }
```

I want to speed up the running time of this code by distributing it across multiple machines in a cluster. I'm using Scala on intelliJ-idea with Spark. How would I implement this type of code to work on multiple machines?

Comment: Sorry, but this is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already stated by [Mariano Kamp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45867/mariano-kamp) Spark is probably not a good choice here and there are much better options out there. To add on top of that any approach which has to work on a relatively large data and requires O(N^2) time is simply unacceptable. So the first thing you should do is to focus on choosing suitable algorithm not a platform.

Still it is possible to translate it to Spark. A naive approach which directly reflects your code would be to use Cartesian product:

```
def check(v1: T, v2: T): Option[U] = {
  if (v1 == v2) {
    None
  } else {
    // rest of your logic, Some[U] if all tests passed
    // None otherwise
    ???
  }
}

val vertexRDD = sc.parallelize(vertexArray)
  .map{case (v1, v2) => check(v1, 2)}
  .filter(_.isDefined)
  .map(_.get)
```

If `vertexArray` is small you could use `flatMap` with broadcast variable

```
val vertexBd = sc.broadcast(vertexArray)

vertexRDD.flatMap(v1 =>
  vertexBd.map(v2 => check(v1, v2)).filter(_.isDefined).map(_.get))
)
```

Another improvement is to perform proper join. The obvious condition is year and month:

```
def toPair(v: T): ((Int, Int), T) = ??? // Return ((year, month), vertex)

val vertexPairs = vertexRDD.map(toPair)

vertexPairs.join(vertexPairs)
  .map{case ((_, _), (v1, v2)) => check(v1, v2) // Check should be simplified
  .filter(_.isDefined)
  .map(_.get)
```

Of course this can be achieved with a broadcast variable as well. You simply have to group `vertexArray` by (year, month) pair and broadcast `Map[(Int, Int), T]`.

From here you can improve further by avoiding naive checks by partition and traversing data sorted by timestamp:

```
def sortPartitionByDatetime(iter: Iterator[U]): Iterator[U] = ???
def yieldMatching(iter: Iterator[U]): Iterator[V] = {
  // flatmap keeping track of values in open window
  ???
}

vertexPairs
  .partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(n))
  .mapPartitions(sortPartitionByDatetime)
  .mapPartitions(yieldMatching)
```

or using a DataFrame with window function and range clause.

Note:

All types are simply placeholders. In the future please try to provide type information. Right now all I can tell is there are some tuples and dates involved

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot. I changed my code a little and I'm only using RDD functions now. Is there a way to tell whether the program is running in a distributed way on just one local machine? I'm running the program using intelliJ idea on windows 10

Comment: The simplest thing you can do is to check Spark UI. It should run on port 4040 by default.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it out :)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately this is not the right approach ;(

Spark is not a tool to parallelize tasks, but to parallelize data.

So you need to think how you can distribute/parallelize/partition your data, then compute the individual partitions, then consolidate the results as a last step.

Also you need to read up on Spark in general. A simple answer here cannot get you started. This is just the wrong format.

Start here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html